# Focus on textarea

Tags: javascript

How would I do the following in javascript:

```
<textarea onload="focus">Here is some text</textarea>
```

Basically, I want the textarea field to be focused on, and I want to do it within the html tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the autofocus attribute:

```
 <textarea autofocus>
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make websites.
</textarea>
```

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_autofocus.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to provide some way to select your textarea, like an ID: `<textarea id="my-textarea"></textarea>`.

Then you can use the DOM API: `document.getElementById('my-textarea').focus()`.

Or use jQuery: `$('#my-textarea').focus()`.